# Putting more items in Bootstrap Navbar

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I have a bootstrap navbar. I want to put signOut and welcome in the menu bar along with other menu items. Below is the screenshot of my navbar:

[image]

I want to put SignOut where the purple arrow is and right beneath "SignOut", I want to put "Welcome userName". I also want to move the logo and company/city name to extreeme left of the nav bar . How can I achieve that? Below is my code:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg py-5 navbar-dark  shadow-sm " style="background-color: #264653;width:100%;" >
  <div class="container">


      <span class="navbar-brand" style="display:flex;">
        
            <img src="~/Images/InfoOrange.png" alt="ACR" width="70" height="70" class="d-inline-block align-middle mr-2" runat="server" />
      
       <span style="font-size:25px;color:white;"><span style="color:#e9c46a">test City</span><br />test company</span>

    </span>

    <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" class="navbar-toggler"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>

    <div id="navbarSupportedContent" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
       <%-- <li class="nav-item active"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>--%>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="userDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Users
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Details</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="Depatment.aspx">Department</a>
     
         <%-- <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sections</a>--%>
        </div>
      </li>
          <li>&nbsp;</li>

              <li class="nav-item dropdown nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="admindropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Admin
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="NewBoxFolder.aspx">Box/Folder</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Configuration</a>

        </div>
      </li>
           <li>&nbsp;</li>
               <li class="nav-item dropdown nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="recordsDropDown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Records
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="FileUpload.aspx">BlockChain Upload</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Verify</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="DocReport.aspx">Report</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="BucketList.aspx">S3 List</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    
    </div>
      <div>
          <ul>
                 
        <li class="nav-item" style="margin-right:5px" >
            <a class="nav-link px-5" href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Pages/SignOut.aspx") %>">Sign Out</a>
        </li>
 
          </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Your 'container' div is keeping you from doing so. Check the max-width in the .container css and adjust to taste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can contain this section with a class. In this instance I called it `<div class="sign">`. Then since your `ul` is a direct child of the parent you can use `.sign > ul` in your CSS to target that div. To get it in that position you can simply apply `absolute positioning` which allows you to define the area of the page. In your application, the top right. You can then add in your **Welcome & Username** area underneath as other unordered list items.

```css
.sign > ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="sign">
   <ul>
      <li class="nav-item" style="margin-right:5px" >
         <a class="nav-link px-5" href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Pages/SignOut.aspx") %>">Sign Out</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```